# How to predict after training data is normalized?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I am learning TensorFlow.js using the official documentation and modified the code [mentioned in Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-regression/index.html#0) to output pounds when given a kg value as input.

So I have a `run` function which runs when DOM is loaded.

```js
async function run() {
    const model = createModel();
    const data = createData();
    const tensorData = convertToTensor(data);
    const { inputs, labels } = tensorData;

    // Train Model
    await trainModel(model, inputs, labels);
    console.log('Training Complete');

    // Predict
    const normalizedPredictData = normalizeData([5]);
    const { normalizedPredictDataVal, predictValMax, predictValMin } = normalizedPredictData;
    const output = model.predict(normalizedPredictDataVal);
    const finalOutput = unNormalizeData(output, predictValMax, predictValMin);
    console.log(finalOutput.print());
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
```

createModel creates a simple sequential model with 2 layers - one hidden layer and one output layer.

```js
function createModel() {
    const model = tf.sequential();

    // Hidden Layer
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [1] }));

    // Output Layer
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1 }));

    return model;
}
```

createData is a function which generates 500 values for training.

```js
function createData() {
    const data = {
        inputs: Array.from({ length: 500 }, (x, i) => i),
        labels: Array.from({ length: 500 }, (x, i) => i * 2.2)
    };

    return data;
}
```

Inputs run from 0 to 499 and labels are just input * 2.2 because I want to predict pounds when a kg value is given as input.

`convertToTensor` function normalizes the generated data after converting it to tensors.

```js
function convertToTensor(data) {
    return tf.tidy(() => {
        tf.util.shuffle(data);

        const inputs = data.inputs;
        const labels = data.labels;

        const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(inputs, [inputs.length, 1]);
        const labelTensor = tf.tensor2d(labels, [labels.length, 1]);

        // Normalize Data
        const inputMax = inputTensor.max();
        const inputMin = inputTensor.min();
        const labelMax = inputTensor.max();
        const labelMin = inputTensor.min();

        const normalizedInputs = inputTensor.sub(inputMin).div(inputMax.sub(inputMin));
        const normalizedLabels = labelTensor.sub(labelMin).div(labelMax.sub(labelMin));

        return {
            inputs: normalizedInputs,
            labels: normalizedLabels,
            inputMax,
            inputMin,
            labelMax,
            labelMin
        };
    });
}
```

Finally the data is trained using `trainModel`

```js
async function trainModel(model, inputs, labels) {
    model.compile({
        optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
        loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError,
        metrics: ['mse']
    });

    const batchSize = 32;
    const epochs = 50;

    return await model.fit(inputs, labels, {
        batchSize,
        epochs,
        shuffle: true,
        callbacks: tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(
            { name: 'Training Performance' },
            ['loss', 'mse'],
            { height: 200, callbacks: ['onEpochEnd'] }
        )
    });
}
```

Now that the data is trained, it's time to predict values. As the model is trained with normalized values, I am only passing normalized input values to predict function.

```js
function normalizeData(value) {
    const predictValTensor = tf.tensor2d(value, [value.length, 1]);

    const predictValMax = predictValTensor.max();
    const predictValMin = predictValTensor.min();

    const normalizedPredictDataVal = predictValTensor.sub(predictValMin).div(predictValMax.sub(predictValMin));

    return {
        normalizedPredictDataVal,
        predictValMax,
        predictValMin
    };
}
```

The above function converts the value to tensor, normalizes it and returns the result which is then passed to predict function for an output value. As the input was normalized, the output needs to be unNormalized so have created a function to unnormalize it.

```js
function unNormalizeData(value, predictMax, predictMin) {
    const unNormPredictVal = value.mul(predictMax.sub(predictMin)).add(predictMin);
    return unNormPredictVal;
}
```

Once the output is unNormalized, I am simply logging it to console. But it is only outputting the value which I had given as input. In this case, the value is 5.

[image]

Code till training data is working fine. I think the error lies where I am trying to normalize and unnormalize the value for predict.

Comment: What is the value of the output before applying the `unNormalizeData` function ?

Comment: @edkeveked 2.0837317 is the output.

Comment: If you can do a snippet using https://stackblitz.com, it will be easier to understand the issue

Comment: @edkeveked Getting [MIME error](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/246) on Stackblitz so have uploaded it on Code Pen, you can find it [here](https://codepen.io/gegobyte/pen/qBEZOpE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predicted value should be normalized by using the max and min value of the training sample.

There should not be `predictValMax` (respectively `predictValMin`) different from `inputMax` (respectively `inputMin`)

```
const predictValMax = predictValTensor.max();
const predictValMin = predictValTensor.min();
```

A prediction of a feature should be invariant by dataset of features. 
Training set of feature

```
[-5, 5], inputMin = -5, inputMax = 5; normalized = [0, 0.5]
```

Given this two test sets of features:

```
[5, 6], predictMin = 5, predictMax = 6; normalized = [0, 1]; 

[5], predictMin = 5, predictMax = 6; normalize = [1] // ( though a division by zero occurs here).
```

The normalized value for 5 is different in the test sets. It is also different from the normalized value in the training data. The model will end up predicting different value for the same feature 5 each time that it occurs because its normalized value is dataset dependant.

This would not happen if the same normalized parameters (`inputMin`, `inputMax`) are applied for each predicted value.

```js
function createModel() {
    const model = tf.sequential();

    // Hidden Layer
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [1] }));

    // Output Layer
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1 }));

    return model;
}

let inputMin, inputMax, labelMin, labelMax

function createData() {
    const data = {
        inputs: Array.from({ length: 500 }, (x, i) => i),
        labels: Array.from({ length: 500 }, (x, i) => i * 2.2)
    };

    return data;
}

function convertToTensor(data) {
    return tf.tidy(() => {
        tf.util.shuffle(data);

        const inputs = data.inputs;
        const labels = data.labels;

        const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(inputs, [inputs.length, 1]);
        const labelTensor = tf.tensor2d(labels, [labels.length, 1]);
      
      inputTensor.print();
labelTensor.print()
        // Normalize Data
        inputMax = inputTensor.max();
        inputMin = inputTensor.min();
        labelMax = inputTensor.max();
        labelMin = inputTensor.min();

        const normalizedInputs = inputTensor.sub(inputMin).div(inputMax.sub(inputMin));
        const normalizedLabels = labelTensor.sub(labelMin).div(labelMax.sub(labelMin));

        return {
            inputs: normalizedInputs,
            labels: normalizedLabels,
            inputMax,
            inputMin,
            labelMax,
            labelMin
        };
    });
}

async function trainModel(model, inputs, labels) {
const learningRate = 0.01;
const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(learningRate);
  // tf.train.adam()
    model.compile({
        optimizer: optimizer ,
        loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError,
        metrics: ['mse']
    });

    const batchSize = 32;
    const epochs = 200;
  inputs.print()
  labels.print()

    return await model.fit(inputs, labels, {
        batchSize,
        epochs,
        shuffle: true,
        callbacks: tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(
            { name: 'Training Performance' },
            ['loss', 'mse'],
            { height: 200, callbacks: ['onEpochEnd'] }
        )
    });
}

function normalizeData(value) {
    const predictValTensor = tf.tensor2d(value, [value.length, 1]);

    //const predictValMax = predictValTensor.max();
    //const predictValMin = predictValTensor.min();

    const normalizedPredictDataVal = predictValTensor.sub(inputMin).div(inputMax.sub(inputMin));

    return {
        normalizedPredictDataVal,
        inputMax,
        inputMin
    };
}

function unNormalizeData(value, predictMax, predictMin) {
    const unNormPredictVal = value.mul(inputMax.sub(inputMin)).add(inputMin);
    return unNormPredictVal;
}

async function run() {
    const model = createModel();
    const data = createData();
    const tensorData = convertToTensor(data);
    const { inputs, labels } = tensorData;

    await trainModel(model, inputs, labels);
    console.log('Training Complete');

    const normalizedPredictData = await normalizeData([1000, 6, 7]);
  console.log('normalizedinput')
  normalizedPredictData.normalizedPredictDataVal.print()
    const { normalizedPredictDataVal, predictValMax, predictValMin } = normalizedPredictData;
    const output = await model.predict(normalizedPredictDataVal);
    console.log(output.print());
    const finalOutput = await unNormalizeData(output, predictValMax, predictValMin);
     console.log(finalOutput.print());
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-vis@1.0.2/dist/tfjs-vis.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```